# Using apache poi in java to generate excel line chart

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

i am using apache poi to generate line chart in excel. I have two sets of data, and it works well, please look at picture1.

**picture1**
[image]

When i use only one set of data, it generate picture2, and you can see the right side of the picture, it show china, usa and japan. This is not what i want, it should show only one serial on right side. How can i fix this?

**picture2**
[image]

maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

java code

```
public static void test() throws Exception {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

            String sheetName = "CountryLineChart";

            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 26);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            chart.setTitleText("Area-wise Top Seven Countries");
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle("Country");
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle("Area & Population");

            XDDFDataSource<String> countries = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(new String[] { "china", "usa", "japan" });

            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> area = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(new Double[] { 12d, 22d, 12d });

            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> population = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(new Double[] { 33d, 12d, 16d });

            XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

            XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(countries, area);
            series1.setTitle("Area", null);
            series1.setSmooth(false);
            series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.STAR);

            // if comment these code, it generate line chart like picture2
            // ===========================================================================
            XDDFLineChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(countries, population);
            series2.setTitle("Population", null);
            series2.setSmooth(true);
            series2.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.SQUARE);
            // ===========================================================================

            chart.plot(data);

            // Write output to an excel file
            String filename = "/Users/jiangxingshang/Downloads/tmp/line-chart.xlsx";
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For only one series do `XDDFLineChartData.setVaryColors(false)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054458/poi-bar-chart-generate-one-series-has-question/56078657#56078657 for same problem with bar chart.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, it's solved. Could you post an answer so i can finish this question.